# CLANG_WARN_NULLABLE_TO_NONNULL_CONVERSION removed?

Tags: ios, clang, objective-c-nullability

Seems like `CLANG_WARN_NULLABLE_TO_NONNULL_CONVERSION` was removed in Xcode 8. It provided some really good warnings in case `nil` was passed to `nonnull` parameters/return types. Any idea why this was removed and whether there exists a replacement?

Answer (score 0):

I still see warning, when I pass nil to nonull expected method. Maybe it's enabled by default for now.